# Sound is completely gone after temporarily muting my computer

Tags: sound

I've been using Ubuntu for 2 months now, and the sound always worked fine. Today I muted my computer for a while, and now the sound is completely gone, even after rebooting my computer a couple of times.

Answer (score 2):

Open `alsamixer` in terminal. You should then see all output possibilities of your sound card. Check that all bars (where possible) are set to `00` instead of `MM`. You mute/unmute with by pressing the `m`-key. When unmuting master for example, you will still need to manually regulate the volume once (by the indicator for example) to hear an effect. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did this, and every bar was set to 00. The master bar was completely down, I brought it up to maximum now. Unfortenately I still have no sound.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that a couple of likely candidates could be at fault here.

Open the volume control panel and check these options:

[image: Output tab]
See that they are configured as they should be, with the correct device selected, and the correct output selected from the drop down list.

[image: Hardware tab]
Also make sure you have the correct profile and that your volume is up as needed. You can also check your speakers from here.

As mentioned in another answer, you can use `alsamixer` from a Terminal:
[image: Alsamixer]